# Sparkline in SSRS 2008R2/BIDS with fixed axis

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, sparklines

I'm having some difficulty getting a sparkline chart to display correctly and the Microsoft documentation is focused on Report Builder.

I have a collection of items that can be placed in one of a number of bins.  I'm trying to show the frequency of occurrence for each item/bin number combination.  While I *could* sum the items by bin number in SQL, I'm letting SSRS do it for now.

For the purposes of explanation, assume the dataset looks something like this:

```
Item,Bin
-----------
A,1
A,2
A,5
A,2
B,1
B,5
```

I've got the item bit down -- the table containing the sparkline has a row group that groups on the appropriate variable (Item).  For the horizontal axis, I've selected the bin # as the property being graphed.  I'm not sure what to use to get the vertical axis though.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the value set for the sparkline? It's not clear from your explanation if you have done this step. If not, just click the sparkline to display the Chart Date pane. Click the plus sign in the Values section and then select Expression. It sounds like you want to count the number of items by bin so you use this expression:

```
=Count(Fields!Item.Value)
```

Because you have sequential bins, you might consider setting the Horizontal Axis properties to a Scalar axis type so that you get the right sequencing and "fill in the blanks" if a bin number is missing for a particular item (such as 3 and 4 for Item A in your example). Also set the Align Axes property to your tablix so that all bin numbers line up in your sparklines in each row. Otherwise you would get 1 and 2 for Item A above 1 and 5 for Item B. With the Align Axes properties the 5 for A and the 5 for B would line up correctly.

Comment: What I'm getting now doesn't make any sense.  I have both axes aligned within the tablix.  But the graph isn't displaying as I'd expect.  I'd expect to have 5 slots for vertical bars (based on the example above), with 3 bars in the tablix row for item A, and 2 bars in the row for item B.  What I'm actually getting is 3 bars in the one row, 2 in the other, and they're not aligning.

Comment: Did you set the axis type to scalar? Can you confirm what you see in the Chart Data pane for Values and for Category Groups and that Series Groups is empty?

Comment: Also you only need to align the horizontal axis. Do not do this for the vertical axis. The problem is more likely to be something in the horizontal axis, though